No me permite Flask cargar los datos en la BD
estoy haciendo un backend y frontend con Flask, hasta ahora todo iba bien hasta cargar los datos en la base de datos de los libros (estoy haciendo una web de una libreria con usuarios, autores y libros). El template de autores me permite sin ningún problema cargar, pero al ingresar los datos de los libros (así como la relación con los autores, fk) me arroja "Data Required". Les paso el model, el forms, rutas y template para que me expliquen que rayos es, ya que ni la ia puede explicarme bien a que se debe:
routes.py:
@routes.route('/nuevo_libro',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def nuevo_libro():
    libro = Libro()
    libroForm = LibroForm(obj=libro)
    if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.usuario != 'anonimo':
        if libroForm.validate_on_submit():
            libro.titulo = libroForm.titulo.data
            libro.genero = libroForm.genero.data
            libro.precio = libroForm.precio.data
            libro.cantidad = libroForm.cantidad.data
            libro.autor_id = libroForm.autor_id.data
            db.session.add(libro)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Libro guardado exitosamente!','success')
            return redirect(url_for('routes.inicio_libro'))
        else:
            for field, errors in libroForm.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    flash(f"Error en {field}: {error}", 'danger')
    return render_template('nuevo_libro.html',libroform=libroForm)

models.py:
class Autor(db.Model):
    id =  db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    nombre = db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)
    apellido =  db.Column(db.String(50),nullable=False)
    libros = db.relationship('Libro',backref='autor.id',lazy=True)

# Clase Libro
class Libro(db.Model):
    id =  db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    titulo = db.Column(db.String(200),nullable=False)
    genero = db.Column(db.String(100),nullable=False)
    precio = db.Column(db.Float,default=0)
    cantidad = db.Column(db.Integer,default=0)
    autor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('autor.id'), nullable=False)

forms.py:
class LibroForm(FlaskForm):
    titulo = StringField('Título',validators=[DataRequired()])
    genero = StringField('Género',validators=[DataRequired()])
    precio = FloatField('Precio',validators=[DataRequired()])
    cantidad = IntegerField('Cantidad',validators=[DataRequired()])
    autor_id = SelectField('Autor',coerce=int,validators=[DataRequired()])
    enviar = SubmitField('Guardar')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LibroForm,self).__init__(args, **kwargs)
        self.autor_id.choices=[(autor.id, f'{autor.nombre} {autor.apellido}') for autor in Autor.query.all()]

class AutorForm(FlaskForm):
    nombre = StringField('Nombre',validators=[DataRequired()])
    apellido = StringField('Apellido',validators=[DataRequired()])
    enviar = SubmitField('Guardar')

nuevo_libro.html:
{% extends "form_template.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>Nuevo libro</h2>
    {% if current_user.is_authenticated and current_user.usuario != 'anonimo' %}
    <div>
        <form action="{{ url_for('routes.nuevo_libro') }}" method="POST" novalidate>
            {{ libroform.hidden_tag() }}
            <div>
                {{ libroform.titulo.label }}
                {{ libroform.titulo(size=100) }}<br>
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ libroform.genero.label }}
                {{ libroform.genero(size=100) }}<br>
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ libroform.precio.label }}
                {{ libroform.precio }}<br>
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ libroform.cantidad.label }}
                {{ libroform.cantidad }}<br>
                {% for error in libroform.cantidad.errors %}
                <div class="text-danger">{{ error }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ libroform.autor_id.label }}
                {{ libroform.autor_id }}<br>
                {% for error in libroform.autor_id.errors %}
                <div class="text-danger">{{ error }}</div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div>
                {{ libroform.enviar() }}
            </div>
        </form>
        <p>Volver al <a href="{{ url_for('routes.index') }}"><b>Inicio</b></a></p>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
            {% if messages %}
                <div class="alerts">
                    {% for category, message in messages %}
                        <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
                            {{ message }}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% else %}
        <p>
            Acceso denegado, para poder agregar un nuevo libro debes estar correctamente 
            <a href="{{ url_for('routes.register') }}"><b>registrado</b></a> ó <a href="{{ url_for('routes.login') }}"><b>iniciar sesión</b></a>
        </p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

Es mi primera vez haciendo un post en stack, disculpen si parece todo atado con alambre jajaja.

despues de ver y reever, pude resolverlo con la ayuda de la IA (que en realidad me di cuenta releyendo el código ni la IA se percató).
El problema radicaba en que al momento de cargar el formulario con la info el constructor:
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(LibroForm,self).__init__(args, **kwargs)
    self.autor_id.choices=[(autor.id, f'{autor.nombre} {autor.apellido}') for autor in Autor.query.all()]

en el super, que es utilizado por la herencia del padre LibroForm, en args me faltaba el *. Una vez agregué eso, se solucionó. Que manera te put3ar.
